# "TypeError: _vm.$v.form is undefined"

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

Hello I want to validate a form with vuelidate but I am facing a certain problem(Details below). I have done this before in other components and pages, there were no errors, so I don’t understand what the problem could be, I checked all the code and didn’t notice any errors.  I'm using Vue 2

I connected it globally:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'
import App from './App.vue'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
export const show = new Vue()
Vue.use(Vuelidate)
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

this is my form in register view:

```html
<form @submit.prevent="submitHandler" class="authentication-template__form" action="">
                    <div class="authentication-template__form-item">
                        <p>Пароль</p>
                        <input 
                        type="password"
                        v-model.trim="form.password"
                        :class="$v.form.phone.$error ? 'invalid' : ''"
                        >
                        <!--<p v-if="$v.form.password.$dirty && !$v.form.password.required" class="invalid-feedback">Обязательное поле для заполнения</p>-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="authentication-template__form-item">
                        <p>Повторите пароль</p>
                        <input 
                        type="password"
                        v-model.trim="form.repeatPassword"
                        >
                        <!--<p v-if="$v.form.repeatPassword.$dirty && !$v.form.repeatPassword.required" class="invalid-feedback">Обязательное поле для заполнения</p>-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="authentication-template__button">
                        <button class="button" type="submit">
                            {{buttonText}}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

my scripts:

```js
import { required, minLength, sameAs } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

export default {
    data: () => ({
        name: 'registration2',
        title: 'Регистрация',
        buttonText: 'Зарегистрироваться',
        form: {
            password: '',
            repeatPassword: ''
        }
    }),
    methods: {
        submitHandler(){
            this.$v.form.$touch()
            if(!this.$v.form.$error){
                this.$router.push('/')
            }
        }
    },
    components:{
        AuthenticationTemplateRoles
    },
    validations: {
        password: {required},
        repeatPassword: {required}
    }
}
</script>
```

When I run it, the console gives 2 errors: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.$v.form is undefined" and _vm.$v.form is undefined

Comment: according to [docs](https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-data-nesting) nested objects should be called like so in `validations`. eg: `validations:{ form { password :{required} }}`.